# Android Error Keystore error: Cannot recover key

Tags: java, android, android-studio, keystore, keytool

I changed the keystore password on Mac through the command line like so:

> 1) Open Terminal and cd to where your .jks is located
>
> 2) keytool -storepasswd -new NEWPASSWORD -keystore YOURKEYSTORE.jks
>
> 3) enter your current password

When I now try to generate a signed APK I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key user_key from store "/Users/user/Documents/App Information/user_key.jks": Cannot recover key
```

When I enter the current password in the command line it works so it is not as if I am entering the wrong password. I have invalidated the cache too. I can change this password correctly through the command line again with no errors.

*I have also checked the directory path of the key, this is correct also.*

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

If I reset the password to what it was originally it works?

Comment: Did you enter the new password in Android Studio too?

Answer (score -3):

I believe that your "Key password" is wrong

[Generate Signed APK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFdb5.jpg)